# How do I use the normal controller test assertions in Minitest Spec DSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I usually write my specs in RSpec but I use Minitest too.
Recently I learnt that there is a minitest dsl that could read like RSpec. They call it Minitest::Spec. I have checked it out and I think I like it. The `gem 'minitest-rails'` makes the setup configuration easy. There is however one limitation I have faced and that is in the integration specs. What is the equivalent for assertions like `assert_response`, `assert_no_difference`, and `assert_template`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen an answer. It turned out that I got them in the very gem that supplied the test expectations. I looked into the source code of the `minitest/rails/controller.rb` and I saw the simple way those expectations were implemented is by aliasing the real minitest assertions. Here is my find

```
class ActionController::TestCase # :nodoc:
  alias :must_respond_with :assert_response
  alias :must_redirect_to :assert_redirected_to
  alias :must_render_template :assert_template
  alias :must_select :assert_select
  alias :must_select_email :assert_select_email
  alias :must_select_encoded :assert_select_encoded
end
```